# querySelectorAll() in java script return zero

Tags: javascript, html

I added elements in html page using JS, then I use query Selector All("element . class name") to access this element but it return zero.
However the elements displayed in my web page.

```js
var listItems=document.querySelectorAll(".list-items");
var x=listItems[0].querySelectorAll("img.list-item-img").length;
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div class="list-items" id="mostReleaseList">
                    <!-- her will be tags by JS -->
</div>
```

Comment: There are no images with the `list-item-img` class in that `div`.

Comment: "_here __will be__ tags by JS_", they've to be there at the time you make the query.